# Detect beep sound from Audio file using python

Tags: python, audio, detect, beep

Detect beep sound from Audio file using python
this code I found from somewhere but it is not giving the actual beep result
means in the audio where beep is not there then also this code is showing beep in it

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
#from time import sleep
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

filename = 'C:/Users/YahyaSirguroh/Downloads/output.mp4'

video = VideoFileClip(filename)
audio = video.audio
duration = video.duration 
audio.write_audiofile("audio.wav")
#sleep(0.3)
samplerate, data = wavfile.read('audio.wav')

step = 30
audio_signal = []
cnt = 0
flag = 0
text = ''
for t in range(int(duration*step)): 
    t = t/step
    if cnt:
        flag+=1
    if t > audio.duration or t > video.duration: break
    audio_frame = audio.get_frame(t) #numpy array representing mono/stereo values
    audio_signal.extend(list(audio_frame))
    if (audio_frame>0.6).sum()==2:
        cnt+=1
        
   
    if cnt>=2:
        print('beep detected at %5.2f' %(t))
        text = 'beep detected at %d' %(np.round(t))
       
    if flag>=4:
        cnt=0
        flag=0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Simply i want to detect in a video file where the beep noise is coming and want to find the timestamp of that

Comment: Any lead? I am also trying to detect whistle noise from audio file.

Comment: see also [Find sound effect inside an audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572693/find-sound-effect-inside-an-audio-file)